# preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '@' found

Tags: php, preg-replace, bbcode

I am new at php and I was trying to create a BBcode but it gives me this error:

> Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '@' found

The code I did:

```
function bbCode($str){
    $values = array(
                    '@\[b]\(.*?)\[\/b]\@i' => '<b>$1</b>',
                    '@\[i]\(.*?)\[\/i]\@i' => '<em>$1</em>'

                    );
                    return preg_replace(array_keys($values), array_values($values), $str);
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: `@\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]@i` should works

Comment: Do you know the difference between `@` and `\@`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your escaping the last `@` symbol by using `\@` so php is interpreting the @ as a literal @ rather than the delimiting character.

**EDIT:**

```
function bbCode($str)
{
    $values = array(
      '@\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]@i' => '<b>$1</b>',
      '@\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]@i' => '<em>$1</em>'

    );
    return preg_replace(array_keys($values), array_values($values), $str);
}
```

Comment: If I do this it gives me other error: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses

Comment: try my edited solution

Comment: It's not as if it wasn't [documented](http://es1.php.net/preg_replace): *`pattern` - The pattern to search for. It can be either a string or an array with strings.*

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario right you are, I've fixed my solution.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me why? I don't want to just get the answer, I want to understand it.

Comment: My first sentence explains why it didn't work. Your `@` symbol is being used as a delimiter, but because you had written `\@` it was being interpreted as part of the regex. Read here for more info about escaping characters: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: Ah ok because of '@@'